Combining border-radius with clip-path to show the oposite direction
How can an image be styled so that the border radius of all corners is 30px, but the border right has a skew?

All the corners should be rounded:
border-radius: 30px;

I tried using clip-path but with that the border radius can't be added:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/4E0744CD-793A-4EF8-B550B54F7F2C4406_source.jpg">
  </div>
</body>




The intended result is unclear. Could you provide a complete shape so we can see all the corners?

You could use svg clipping: svg id=clipPolygon>defs>clipPath>path would be elements in html, use attribute clip-path="url(#clipPolygon)" in img for complex clipping, however the custom path have to be generated by you using bezier curve,etc. you can experiment with svg paths to make required clipping mask and use it..

You can rely on skew transformation


.image {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px; /* the radius */
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top ;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transform-origin: inherit;
  transform: skewX(20deg); /* use the opposite value */
}
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/4E0744CD-793A-4EF8-B550B54F7F2C4406_source.jpg">
</div>



